# How to use select query in hibernate Dao implementation

Tags: sql

```
select rg.guardian_name,
       rg.guardian_id,
       rg.guardian_email 
from rts_guardian rd, rts_ward rw, rts_wrdgrd_junction junct 
where rg.guardian_id = junct.guardian_id and rw.ward_id=junct.ward_id and rw.garde='VIII';
```

Comment: what is the question ?

Comment: actually i got this query   from my manager to implement in Hibernate Dao.

Answer (score 1):

You can begin by this simple example :

```
Query query = session.createQuery
              ("select stock_code, stock_name from backup_stock where id_stock= :id");
```

Here is how you can set parameters :

```
query.setParameter("id", "1");
```

And to get the result:

```
List list = query.list();
```

please search more before asking here. You can find many documentation on this subject so make an effort.